# PHP Mailer Embed Image from $_GET

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to embed an image into an email that comes from a form on a previous page however when I send the email it says that the image doesnt exist. I am using $_GET to pull the image file name and then put it into the src of the image. I have a feeling I have done the path in the "AddEmbeddedImage" part wrong however am not sure how to put it inside. If I put the $_GET['imagebase64'] in the src of the image inside the HTML and look at the source code of the email, it gives me the file name, so I know it is pulling it across properly.

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('"/images/visitor-photos/'.$_GET['imagebase64'].'"', 'visitorimg');

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Your visitor has arrived!';
    $mail->Body    = '<div style="font-family: Open Sans; text-align:center;">
        <p style="margin-bottom:10px; font-size:30px;">'.ucfirst($_GET['firstName']). " " . ucfirst($_GET['lastName']) .' has just signed in and is waiting for you at reception.</p><br>
        <img width=500 height=375 src="cid:visitorimg"/><br>
        <img width=400 height=75 style="margin-top=150px;" src="/images/VMS-Logo.png"/></div>';
```

Comment: I'd recommend validating what's in `$_GET['imagebase64']` against a whitelist of allowed filenames before you use it. Otherwise you're looking at path traversal / file inclusion vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the double quotes there, try this (and check if the path is right):

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('/images/visitor-photos/'.$_GET['imagebase64'], 'visitorimg');
```

Comment: I have added that and still didnt work however it seems to only work if the image is in the root of where the php file is.

Comment: Then check your path, you might need to give the absolute path